# Cadastro de produtos usando PySimpleGUI e Python

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

Gostaria de uma ajuda.

Estou treinando neste código:

```
    categoria = ['Celular', 'Bateria', 'Carregador']
    marca = ['Iphone', 'Motorola', 'LG']
    cor = ['Branco', 'Verde', 'Preto']
    fonte = 20

    layout = [[sg.Text('Código', font=fonte), sg.Input(key='-COD-', font=fonte, size=(20, 1))],
      [sg.Text('Unidade', font=fonte), sg.InputText(key='-UNID-', font=fonte, size=(10, 1))],
      [sg.Text('Nome', font=fonte), sg.Input(key='-NOME-', size=(30, 1))],
      [sg.Text('Categoria', font=fonte), sg.Combo(categoria, font=fonte, key='-CATEG-', size=(30, 1))],
      [sg.Text('Marca', font=fonte), sg.Combo(marca, font=fonte, key='-MARCA-')],
      [sg.Text('Cor/Estampa', font=fonte), sg.Combo(cor, font=fonte, key='-COR-')],
      [sg.Text('')],
      [sg.Button('Cadastrar', font=fonte), sg.Button('Cancelar', font=fonte)]]

    window = sg.Window('CADASTRO DE PRODUTOS', layout, size=(700, 300))

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancelar'):
            break
        if event == 'Cadastrar':
            window['-NOME-'].update(window['-CATEG-'])


    window.close()
```

Gostaria que o valor escolhido no Combo cuja `key='-CATEG-'` fosse preenchido na `key= '-NOME-'`. Mas está retornando o objeto e não o valor escolhido, tipo o seguinte:

```
<PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Combo object at 0x7fd8bf982a60>.
```

E outra coisa: Tem como concatenar as `key`: `-CATEG-` + `-MARCA-` + `-COR-` sendo esta junção colocada na `key`=`-NOME-`?. Exemplo: No Combo 'Categoria' foi escolhido a opção Celular; na 'Marca, Motorola e na 'Cor',  Preto. Assim, o campo 'Nome' deveria ser: Celular Motorola Preto.

Além disso, é uma boa prática criar variáveis para definir alguns parâmetros, conforme fiz no caso da fonte? Pensei assim por acreditar que será mais fácil realizar manutenção.

Comment: import PySimpleGUI27 as sg form=sg.FlexForm('Simple data entry form')

Comment: ta faltando estas linha no começo

Answer (score 0):

Para que isso ocorra você tem que definir a variável da `Key`, conforme o seguinte:

```
-CATEG- = values['-CATEG-']
```

Para transformar o valor '-CATEG-' em '*NOME*'

```
_CATEG_ = values['-CATEG-']
_NOME_  = values['_CATEG_']
```

Dessa forma o valor se torna uma variável e pode ser também concatenado.